# Uploading big file to FTP using FtpWebRequest results in "The underlying connection was closed"

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, console-application, .net-4.5

I am trying to upload a relatively big file to an FTP server (250-300mb). I do this in a console application.

My program works fine when the files is a couple of MB, but the big one results in an:

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
```

I have tried to set the timeout, but I still get the error.

Any idea how to modify my code, so I don't get the error?

**My upload code**:

```
using(var fs = File.OpenRead(zipFileName)) 
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                ms.SetLength(fs.Length);
                fs.Read(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int) fs.Length);

                FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpUrl + "/" + zipFileName);
                ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUid, ftpPassword);
                ftp.Timeout = 30000;
                ftp.KeepAlive = true;
                ftp.UseBinary = true;
                ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;


                byte[] buffer = new byte[ms.Length];
                ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ms.Close();

                Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
                ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ftpstream.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Try uploading the same file with an FTP program. Maybe it is a server problem. And increase the timeout or disable it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used your code to upload a 1 GB file to my FTP server. I too got the System.Net.WebException. To fix it, I set the timeout to -1 (do not timeout). After that, the upload worked.

```
ftp.Timeout = -1; // No Timeout
```

On another note, I'm not sure why you are reading the file into a MemoryStream and then putting it into a byte[] buffer. It'd be faster and use less memory to copy the FileStream to the FTP RequestStream.

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(zipFileName))
{
    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpUrl + "/" + zipFileName);
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUid, ftpPassword);
    ftp.Timeout = -1;
    ftp.KeepAlive = true;
    ftp.UseBinary = true;
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
    fs.CopyTo(ftpstream); // Copy the FileStream to the FTP RequestStream
    ftpstream.Close();

    // You should also check the response
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine("Code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine("Desc: {0}", response.StatusDescription);
}
```

Comment: I have used same code for transfer but application throw "Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." Upload data size is: -310MB